# Image Slider Error Android Application

Tags: java, android, debugging, slideshow

Hi everyone I'm new to building android applications and I have a question, I don't not understand why this part of the code for `mDemo = (SliderLayout)findviewById(R.id.slider)` is an error?

is it because I didn't import anything under SliderLayout?

Here is my code

```
package com.example.imageslider;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.imageslider.SliderLayout;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SliderLayout mDemoSlider;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

    HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
}
```

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >
 <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
    custom:auto_cycle="true"
    custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
    custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />

<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
    custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
    custom:selected_drawable="@string/hello_world"
    custom:shape="oval"
    custom_selected_drawable="@string/hello_world"
    custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
    custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
    custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
    custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    custom:selected_width="6dp"
    custom:selected_height="6dp"
    custom:unselected_width="6dp"
    custom:unselected_height="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"    
     />

 <ListView
    android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
    android:id="@+id/transformers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

SliderLayout
    package com.daimajia.slider.library;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class SliderLayout extends RelativeLayout {

public SliderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

}
```

Thanks I using this website as references https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have

```
import com.example.imageslider.SliderLayout;
```

But in your XML you have

```
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
```

Thus when you cast the view R.id.slider, it has the wrong type. Try changing your import line to

```
import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;
```

Comment: Hi @Bruce I just changed my import line but I'm still facing the same issue. It said it "cannot cast from view to sliderlayout".

Comment: What does your SliderLayout class extend? Since it's a "layout" I would expect it to extend ViewGroup, FrameLayout, or one of the other standard Android parent-view classes. At any rate, View needs to be an ancestor class for you to cast it. Is this a compiler error, or a ClassCastException at run time?

Comment: Then what class is your SliderLayout extending?

Comment: It is extending RelativeLayout

Comment: Then that doesn't make sense. Can you post the imports and class declaration for you SliderLayout? The one you have now in your question doesn't show any superclass for SliderLayout. I assume the XML you posted is the one you are using, and the onCreate code is where you are crashing, when you assign to mDemoSlider, right?

Comment: I don't know. I don't see the problem, sorry. Could it be something like your reference of the library is not working?

Comment: I think it is. After I cleaned my project, i have a compile error saying "R  cannot be resovlved". But my XML is having issues saying multiple annotations found at this line under <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout>. I'm going to update my XML for you to see